# Centroid of an implicitly defined plane region

Tags: plotting, regions, implicit

An implicit curve could be something such as:

$$(x/exp(y))^2+y^2=1,$$

Code:

```
(x/Exp[y])^2 + y^2 == 1
```

which is the boundary of a plane region. How can its centroid be found?

Answer (score 6):

```
plot = ContourPlot[(x/Exp[y])^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}];
solid = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[plot];
solidcenter = RegionCentroid[solid]
solidgraph = 
 Graphics[{FaceForm[Directive[Green, Opacity[.2]]], 
   EdgeForm[Directive[Brown, AbsoluteThickness[5]]], solid, Red, 
   Point[solidcenter]}]
```

> `{-0.0000145217, 0.24011}`

[image]

```
hollow = DiscretizeGraphics[plot];
hollowcenter = RegionCentroid[hollow]
hollowgraph = 
 Graphics[{{PointSize[0], hollow}, Red, Point[hollowcenter]}]
```

> `{2.05425*10^-6, 0.246728}`

[image]

Comment: many thanks but there seems to be some typos could you fix them

Comment: many thanks for the correction and may I confirm that by using == in ContourPlot, this centroid is that of the solid region or of the hollow region?

Comment: @feynman If we using `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`，the region is solid. If we replace `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` with `DiscretizeGraphics`,the region is the hollow region.

Comment: thanks a million! you seem to have a redundant part of 'reg, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[center]' (having it twice)?

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version
```

> "12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[(x/Exp[y])^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}];
ctr = RegionCentroid[reg];
ContourPlot[(x/Exp[y])^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}
 , Epilog -> {
   Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]
   , Point@ctr
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: You should indicate which version you used. On my Mac, this works with v13.0.1 but not v13.1, v13.2, or v13.2.1

Comment: many thanks and may I confirm that by using == in ImplicitRegion, this centroid is that of the solid region or of the hollow region?

Comment: Define: `reg2 = ImplicitRegion[(x/Exp[y])^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}]` and plot: `RegionPlot[reg2
 , PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
 , Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@RegionCentroid[reg2]}
 ]` to see the difference.